# How to Pass String Array from RecyclerView Adapter to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-bundle

I am retrieving values from Adapter and storing Values in `ArrayList<String>`.I am converting ArrayList to String Array and passing the Array from RecyclerView Adapter to Other Fragment, but I am getting null values in other `Fragment`.
This is code for converting `ArrayList<String>` into String Array and send to Other Fragment

```
String []tablesId=new String[tableId.size()];
           tablesId=tableId.toArray(tablesId);
        TableAssignConfirm confirm=new TableAssignConfirm();
           Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
               bundle.putStringArray("tablesIds",tablesId);
               confirm.setArguments(bundle);
```

This is code to retrieve the Values from `Bundle` in Other Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_assign_confirm, container, false);
       // Bundle bundle=getArguments().getStringArray("tableIds");
        String []getTables=getArguments().getStringArray("tableIds");
        Log.i("ids", Arrays.toString(getTables));
        return v;
    }
```

How to resolve this and get the Values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
if(bundle!=null){
    String []getTables=bundle.getStringArray("tableIds");
 }
```

in your code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_assign_confirm, container, false);
       Bundle bundle=getArguments();
       if(bundle!=null){
          String []getTables=bundle.getStringArray("tableIds");
        }
        Log.i("ids", Arrays.toString(getTables));
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting error                                                                            Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Satya happy to help u

Comment: When I am printing this array in Log  String []getTables=getArguments().getStringArray("tableIds");
            Log.i("ids",Arrays.toString(getTables));    I am not printing Vaalues. Is array Empty ?

Comment: @Satya may be check here `tablesId=tableId.toArray(tablesId);` that the value are inserted in your array or not

Comment: Yes.When I print in Log I am getting This,    04-03 11:21:37.989 21005-21005/biz.fyra.bookapp I/tables: [10, 9]

Comment: @Satya try to print data like this `for (int i = 0; i < tablesId.length; i++) {
            Log.e("DATA", tablesId[i]);
        }`

Comment: String []tablesId=new String[tableId.size()];
               tablesId=tableId.toArray(tablesId);                                                    Value is not inserted in String Array

Comment: @Satya add values like this **`for (int i = 0; i < tableId.size(); i++) {
            tablesId[i]=tableId.get(i);
        }`**

Answer (score 0):

Check your `getStringArray()` value. It should be `getStringArray("tablesIds")`. Be more attentive next time))

Comment: Reaching 50 reputation is hard((

Comment: Getting Error after doing this change                                         
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

> **Create an interface in your adapter**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
  void onItemClicked(int position, ArrayList<DeliveryTimeSlot> list);
}
```

> **in your adapter call from fragment**

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context, list, new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int position, ArrayList<String> list) {
                  // Handle list and perform actions here
            }
        });
```

> **on your adapter**

```
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener; // Global scope
```

> **in constructor call:**

```
this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
```

> **on your item clicked event :**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position, _list);
    }
});
```